# Content fade-in as user scrolls browser window

Tags: html, user-interface

I'm discovering more websites that perform this visual trick where as you scroll down the browser window, the content fades into view.

I'm wondering how this trick is done and (more importantly) why?  I'm guessing that for exceptionally long pages, the content isn't fetched until you actually reveal that div, image, whatever therefore saving bandwidth?

Lastly, what is this technique called?

Here's a link that triggered my curiosity:
http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/09/showcase-of-games-developed-using-html5-canvas/

Thanks!

Comment: As @Alex's links states, it can be used to reduce server load and save bandwidth.  How often do you go to a web-site, read the opening paragraph, lose interest and scroll no further?  What if that page had 100s of imaages loaded out of the viewport? You never even saw them, no point to load them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload - that sort of thing?

Comment: Ah...yah...page source reveals it is indeed the lazyload plug-in for jQuery...thanks!